# Get last row by timestamp in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have some slowly changing metadata that is stored in real-time onto HDFS.  I would like to write a pig job that condenses these rows down to the most recent row for each key.

For example, for these data (column headers added for clarity):

```
ts   meta   key
--   ----   ---
1    foo    id1
2    que    id2
3    que    id2
4    foo    id1
5    pasa   id2
6    pasa   id2
7    foo    id1
8    pasa   id2
9    pasa   id2
10   pasa   id2
11   pasa   id2
12   hombre id2
13   foo    id1
14   foo    id1
15   hombre id2
16   bar    id1
17   bar    id1
18   bar    id1
19   bar    id1
20   bar    id1
```

I would expect to get the output:

```
15   hombre id2
20   bar    id1
```

I am just starting to learn the ins and outs of Pig Latin - is there a built-in way to do this in pig or some library already, or should I look at writing a UDF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good place for a nested foreach:

```
A = LOAD '$input' AS (ts:int, meta:chararray, key:chararray);
B =
    FOREACH (GROUP A BY key) {
        byts = ORDER A BY ts DESC;
        newest = LIMIT byts 1;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(newest);
    };
```

Testing on your data (I converted it to be tab-delimited):

```
(20,bar,id1)
(15,hombre,id2)
```

With this method you're guaranteed just a single row for each key even if you have two lines with the latest timestamp (though this may not matter for your data).

Comment: Thanks, this worked well.  I'm a bit worried that sorting will not scale as well as the solution from @mr2ert, but ending up with a single result row is desirable, so I will wait until performance issues arise before trying to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is:

```
A = LOAD 'myinput' USING PigStorage(' ') 
    AS (ts:int, meta:chararray, key:chararray) ;

-- Group by key, then find the newest ts for each key
B = FOREACH (GROUP A BY key)
    GENERATE MAX(A.ts) AS newest,
             FLATTEN(A) ;

-- Now that each line has the newest (appropriate) ts, 
-- we can use it to filter the input
C = FILTER B BY newest == ts ;
```

Output:

```
(20,20,bar,id1)
(15,15,hombre,id2)
```

Note that if you don't want to have the duplicate `ts`, you can project it out now like:

```
C = FOREACH (FILTER B BY newest == ts)
    GENERATE A::ts AS ts, A::meta AS meta, A::key AS key ;
```

But it would be better to just leave the extra `ts` alone right now and project it out as part of a later `FOREACH` to limit the number of jobs.

**Update:** This method will return all lines with the greatest `ts` for each key.  For example, if the data is like this:

```
(11,nope,id1)
(20,foo,id1)
(20,bar,id1)
```

Then it will return both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: This solution is nice too - I picked the one from @WinnieNicklaus since it ends up with a single row per key, although I don't really expect timestamp collisions anyway, so either one would probably work just fine.